# Why do I always need to go to grub and enter in Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, grub2

I am using **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS** on **Dell Vostro 15 - 3546**.

`uname -a`  :

```
Linux <laptop-name> 4.15.0-112-generic #113-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 9 23:41:39 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I open my laptop from shutdown the boot screen gets stuck. Hence I followed [this](https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/) and added `nomodeset` after `quiet splash` in **/etc/default/grub**
. Then I further added `acpi_backlight=vendor` after that, due to brightness problems. Now, the line looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

After this, I need to manually hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> during the boot and need to <kbd>Enter</kbd> into `Ubuntu`. However, It still gets stuck on the boot screen, so I need to again hold the <kbd>Power</kbd> button and force shutdown. Then, when I again <kbd>Enter</kbd> into `Ubuntu`, I am finally able to open the device.

This procedure is **too long** and please help me solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should only have nomodeset until you install proprietary nVIdia driver if you have nVidia card/chip. If using it after installing driver it may interfere. Did you install in UEFI boot mode? Have you updated UEFI to latest available?

Comment: @oldfred can you answer here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1273449/1013762

Comment: Remove the nomodeset setting in /etc/default/grub. Use nomodeset as you boot with e on grub menu and add to linux line if you have not installed nVidia driver. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated UEFI and graphic card.
Removed `nomodeset` and it worked !!!

Thanks @oldfred

Answer (score 1):

Try adding/substituting these lines to your /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
#GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` before you reboot.

Comment: I am afraid some of my lines may get wrong. Can you exactly give the updated `/etc/default/grub` according to my file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10alvKlwSatGAfBeahnYA28UQJ46Ptdtd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: OK for your specific example type # at the start of both your GRUB_HIDDEN_ lines and then change yout GRUB_TIMEOUT=1 to GRUB_TIMEOUT=10 and then insert a line and type GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu

Comment: done. Do I have to change this line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset acpi_backlight=vendor"

Comment: Not right now but eventually when you are booting correctly and all your drivers are running as intended you can remove the nomodeset as per @oldfred comment above.

Comment: just take a look at how has my system has changed: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qtkdxrziHszgELBN-CfhWnsoWhwrVEOk/view?usp=sharing.  The laptop continuously hangs and is lagging. PLEASE HELP !!!  In the video, it is not so clear but the up-down transition effect is terrible. Just watch the video in fullscreen

Comment: Have you done a sudo-apt-get update lately? If you are now booting correctly then start a new question regarding the video lag. Ultimately you need to remove nomodeset from your boot command but you need help diagnosing first. Hence a new question with just the details (like your video) and indicate that you have nomodeset in your grub.